# Media sounds play only sometimes on iphone with phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova, core-audio

My application works perfectly on Android, and now I use build from Adobe to compile the app for get the iPhone app. I get it but the sound is reproduced sometimes. I close the application and launch again and all sounds works perfectly, but other times I start the application and any sound is reproduced. I use the next code:

```
media = new Media(path+'sound.m4a', play, error);                       
media.play();
```

I'm breaking my head with this. Help me please.

Comment: Do you perhaps have your vibrate switch turned on on your phone when the sound isn't working?

Comment: (Or you are connected to far away blue-tooth?)

Comment: No, sometimes work and sometimes doesn't work just opening and closing the application. First time never works.

Comment: Not sure what to do then, hopefully someone else can help you!